# Union and Intersection of Family of Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am lost on understanding this concept.  Let  $\lbrace A_n\mid n \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace$ be  an  infinite  family  of  sets  where  $A_n  =  \lbrace 0, 1, 2, \ldots, n\rbrace$.  Consider the universal set here to be $\mathbb{N}$.  How would I find the union up to $10$ and the intersection of up to $10$.  I cannot find anything that explains the concept very well.

Comment: Try something easier first. Can you find the union up to $2$, and the intersection up to $2$? *(I presume "union up to $k$" means "$A_0\cup A_1\cup ...\cup A_k$," and similarly with intersection.)* What about up to $3$? Do you see a pattern?

Comment: You should know how union and intersection work between two sets...  For example $\{1,2\}\cup\{1,2,3,4,5\}=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $\{1,2\}\cap\{1,2,3,4,5\}=\{1,2\}$., intersection and union of more than two sets is essentially the same.  The elements in $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^kA_i$ are those elements which are in *at least one* of the sets $A_i$ and the elements in $\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^kA_i$ are those elements which are in *all* of the sets $A_i$

Comment: So, $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{10}A_i=A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup\dots\cup A_{10}=\{0,1\}\cup\{0,1,2\}\cup\{0,1,2,3\}\cup\dots\cup\{0,1,2,\dots,10\}$ and this simplifies to...

Comment: The only concept is what do all the sets$A_0$ to $A_{10} $ have in common.  Write them out.  What do {0} and {0,1} and {0,1,2} and..... {0,1,2,3...,10} have in common.  It's not a trick question.  That's the intersection.  The only concept of the union is what do you get when you combine them all together.  That also is not a trick question.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try to think about this pictographically:

Draw the set $A_2 = \{0,1,2\}$ as a diagram with those elements floating around in it.

In set theory two sets are considered the same if they have the same elements. Similarly a set is a subset of another if every element of the first is an element of the second.

Therefore it is clear that $A_2 \subset A_3$ and in fact you should try to formulate a proof of $A_n \subset A_{n+k}$ where $k \geq 0$.

Now draw $A_3$. From the above discussion it should be clear that it contains $A_2$ and differs from it only in containing the element $3$.

$A \cap B$ is a symbolised way of saying the set of elements in both $A$ and $B$. Therefore, what's $A_2 \cap A_3$?

$A \cup B$ is asking you what do you get by combining these sets.

Again from our discussion it should be clear that $A_2 \cap A_3 = A_2$ and $A_2 \cup A_3 = A_3$ (since we don't count elements twice in set theory).

Try to generalize this for arbitrary finite unions and intersections to get your answer.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

The key to this problem is to use
for all $n,m \in \mathbb{N}, (n \le m \to A_n \subseteq A_m)$, 
and
for all $A,B$ ($A \subseteq B$ implies $A \cap B = A$ and $A \cup B = B)$.

Comment: Yet again I need to correct somebody's incorrect edit.